# Output of iptables -L after changing policy

Tags: iptables

When I change default policy of INPUT, output of iptables -L stops after third line. I checked it both through ssh and locally. Output of my terminal (yes I know I should not be using root).

```
root@pi4:/# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 73 packets, 16085 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  261 18964 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     192.168.0.0/16       anywhere             tcp dpt:60022
   94  7786 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     192.168.0.0/16       anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     192.168.0.0/16       anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     192.168.0.0/16       anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
    4   962 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     192.168.0.0/16       anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

root@pi4:/# iptables -P INPUT DROP

root@pi4:/# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
^C

root@pi4:/#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's slowing on DNS lookup. Since the new ruleset now prevents DNS replies to be received, for each line there will be some time before a timeout is reached.

You should always use the [`-n`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables.8#n) parameter to avoid DNS lookup. Actually, `-v` should also be used to make some sense of its output. And to be frank, `iptables -L` should almost never be used, especially on stackexchange, because it makes it hard to reproduce what's asked in a question. The only useful case is when a specific match or target displays additional state information on its output.

You should prefer to it one of these:

- [`iptables -S`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables.8#S) for a single table or chain (if provided)
- [`iptables-save -c`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-save.8) for the whole ruleset with packet count (which helps figure out if a rule didn't match)

Anyway you should add a stateful rule to allow reply traffic to be received, including DNS replies:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it was on point. What is DNS looking up thought? Reverse 192.168.0.0/16?

Comment: Yes, for any IP address in the ruleset a reverse DNS lookup was done. Here there was only one: 192.168.0.0